# Editar o return de uma função utilizando o postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Olá!

Tenho a seguinte função(utilizando o pgadmin e postgresql), e gostaria de editar o return de maneira que no "data output" ao invés de aparecer apenas "A soma dos números é: 10", fosse mostrado o " O valor de numero1 + numero2 é 10!"

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION soma(numero1 int, numero2 int)
RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN 'A soma é: ' || numero1 + numero2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT soma(25,2);

Data Output - A soma é: 10

Mas gostaria que fosse mostrado: A soma de 25 + 2 é: 27!

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION soma(numero1 int, numero2 int) RETURNS text AS $$ 
BEGIN 
RETURN 'A soma é: ' concat(numero1, ' + ', numero2, ' = ', numero1 + numero2); 
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```